# Хочу сделать рассылку боту телеграмм

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, бот

Решил сделать рассылку в боте телеграмм. Попробовал код, который сохраняет id пользователя в chatids.txt и потом бот открывает этот файл, берет оттуда id пользователя/групп и рассылает туда сообщения. Но пишет ошибку. Подскажите что не так пожалуйста:

```
# рассылка в боте
@dp.message_handler(commands=["rass"])
async def rass(message):
    print(message.chat.id)
    with open("chatids.txt", "a+") as chatids:
        print(message.chat.id, file=chatids)

@dp.message_handler(commands=["send"])
async def send(message):
    if message.chat.id == 5317208950:
        for i in open("chatids.txt", "r").readlines():
            bot.send_message(i, "тут типо сообщение которое будет отправляться")
```

Ошибка

```
C:\Users\rizny\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\botik\bot.py:113: 
RuntimeWarning: 
coroutine 'Bot.send_message' was never awaited 
bot.send_message(i, "тут типо сообщение которое будет отправляться") 
RuntimeWarning: 
Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: C:\Users\rizny\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\botik\bot.py:113: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Bot.send_message' was never awaited
  bot.send_message(i, "тут типо сообщение которое будет отправляться")
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback @ZxNuClear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед `bot.send_message` забыли добавить `await`

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["send"])
async def send(message):
  if message.chat.id == 5317208950:
    for i in open("chatids.txt", "r").readlines():
      await bot.send_message(i, "тут типо сообщение которое будет отправляться")
```